# Why when updating a mapping of tokens in owners wallet I can add to the number but can't substract

Tags: solidity, mapping

`mapping (address => uint) public ownerTokenCount;`

this runs:    `ownerTokenCount[_msgSender()] = ownerTokenCount[_msgSender()] + 1;`

this causes tx revert  `ownerTokenCount[_msgSender()] = ownerTokenCount[_msgSender()] - 1;`

Comment: There is no problem in adding or removing as you do. Your revert is probably caused by an underflow when subtracting. Are you checking is ownerTokenCount[_msgSender()] is greater than 0 before subtraction ?

Comment: @hroussille Hmm thank you! But that does bring another question :(  why is ownerTokenCount not increasing on mint. I'm just trying to update a mapping when a token is burned.

  `function _mintToken( address _owner) internal {
       ownerSwatCount[_msgSender()] = ownerSwatCount[_msgSender()] + 1;
       _mint;}`

Comment: What does _mint; do ? Btw, maybe I misunderstood but in the code you just provided you increment the ownerSwatCount mapping, not ownerTokenCount. It would make sense then that ownerTokenCount is not increasing.. ?

Comment: @hroussille Ah sorry, my brain is overworked. Pretend it says ownerTokenCount in all instances. it is a erc721 contract. _mint transfers a nft token to the user. And the mint function works. Its only when I try to later update that mapping on a transfer or burn that I am getting reverts.

Comment: Please edit your question to what you are looking for now, or answer your own question if you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this didn't work, and it seems to have fixed itself.
Sorry all.

The token count was updating properly. Something in an earlier line of code was preventing it from calling properly.